# How to fix this error which is stating something is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append this: `'<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '</div>'` when the user clicks on the cancel button (.imageCancel). But it is giving me this error: `$('<div/>').text(value).html();` is not a function. How can this error be fixed? Is it because

```
$('.cancelImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '</div>');
```

is in the `$(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {` function?

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}


function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename) {


    $(".imageCancel").on("click", function (event) {

        $('.cancelImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '</div>');

        var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');
        jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)

        $(this).parent().remove();

        $('.upload_target').get(0).contentwindow

        return stopImageUpload();

    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the function to

```
function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value || '').html(); }
```

I suspect that `.text()` might be a little un-rigorous about testing its argument, and interpreting a `null` as meaning that you want the function to return the current text content of the selected element.

Now, as to *why* the argument would be `null`, well, that depends on the rest of your code.